# Keeping a for loop variable after loop execution

Tags: javascript, for-loop, scope

I am trying to keep a for loop variable after its execution, since the condition will be changing through another for loop. Here's my exemple:

```
l = 0;
for (var i = 0;i<5:i++){
    for(var l; l<l+i;l++){
    }
}
```

My goal here is to remember the value of l when I'm leaving the for loop, and keep it for the next execution with the new condition. I understand this is vague but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just remove `var l`? Or maybe give more details on how is this going to re-run

Comment: what result do you expect? have you tried to access the variables?

Comment: When you declare variables with `var` you already have code that will do what you want.

Comment: Is that an `l` or is it a `1`? As a rule, `l` is a very poor name for a variable.

Comment: @spender: And it won't even execute without throwing an error (in JS). Can't name a var using only numbers nor can a variable start with a number.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `while` loop:

```
var l = 0;
for (var i = 0;i<5:i++){
    while(l < l+i) {
      // do stuff
      l++;
    }
    // Here you have the value of l when breaked out of the loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var l = 0;
for (var i = 0;i<5:i++){
    for(l; l<l+i;l++){
    }
}
```

Will let you retain the latest value for `l`. By the way, without using a `break` I suspect that this will result in **an** infinite **loop**, since `l` will always be less than `l+i` (when `i` is not 0).

Edit: loop not recursion

Comment: No recursion here, but maybe an infinite *loop*.

Answer (score 0):

Your code already works as expected, the `var l` declares the variable in the outer scope so that you can access it outside of the loop.

You will however need to fix the typo (`:`->`;`) and the infinite loop (`l<l+i` is always true for positive `i`), and I'd recommend to put the `var` declaration on the first initialisation of the variable:

```
var l = 0;
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var end = l+i;
    for (; l<end; l++) {
        console.log(i, l);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will work, however you have no reason to be using `var` in 2019, and they also don't effectively take advantage of the for loop syntax.

```
let l = 0;
for (let i = 0; i<5; i++){
    for(; l < i + 1; l++){

    }
}
console.log(l); // 5
```

This example maintains the value of `l` through the outer loop's iterations and then also keeps it at the end.